# how I can know if a input e-mail has value in with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try find a way of know if my input email has some values its in.

I tried this code:

```js
var empty = true;


//get value from my input  type email
    $('input[type="email"]').each(function() {

 //check out if I have some values its in
     if ($(this).val()!="") {
// if my input is empty then its should return this 

 //redefined my var with false
 empty = false;
 //return a console saying that my input is empty
      return  console.log("empty yep");
     }
     
    });
```

what do I trying do?

**I try create a login that when I put something over the input password my javascript detect if I have something in email if I do not have nothing then dont allow continue with the process login in my system without before put the email**

some idea?

Comment: what event are you listening for? and do you want to detect the email format or any value?

Comment: I want to detect if I put a value in the input email if I dont put nothing then dont let me continue writing in the next input , get it me ?

Comment: Okay so let me know if my understanding is correct, that you are trying to stop user from entering password and clicking login when the email is empty ???

Comment: yes I trying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jquery library in head section of HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then add an input tag in HTML code as below

```
<form name="form" action="" method="" onsubmit="validate()">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" required>
</form>
```

then in jquery please paste the below code

```
if($('#email').val() == '') {
    alert('please provide the email').
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Note: you can even validate the email id.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, You need to validate the email to enter the next password input box.

So I have made the password input disabled unless something is entered into email input box.

Using `email.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('disabled',true);` made the password field as disabled.

Then if you start entering into email then the password field will get enabled.

```js
const email = document.querySelector('input[type="email"]');

checkEmailValidation = () => {
  if(email.value){
    email.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    email.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('disabled',true);
  }
}

email.addEventListener('input', checkEmailValidation);

checkEmailValidation();
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="Type email here">
<input type="password" placeholder="Type password here">
```